# Docker name resolution fails

Tags: docker, dns

For quite some time I use docker successfully with a stack defined with a compose file like this:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter:latest
    volumes:
      - /sys:/host/sys:ro
      - /:/rootfs:ro
      - /proc:/host/proc:ro
    deploy:
      mode: global
    networks:
      - monitoring

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:latest
    volumes:
      - /var/apps/monitoring/prometheus-data:/prometheus:rw
      - /var/apps/monitoring/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    networks:
      - monitoring

networks:
  monitoring:
    external: true
    
volumes:
  prometheus-data:
```

Prometheus accessed the exporter service via it's service name `exporter`. But now it stopped working. I suspect some update of one of the components to be responsible but am not able to identify what it is.

**What I already tried:**

I checked that the external network `monitoring` contains both services with

```
docker network inspect monitoring
```

```
[
    {
        "Name": "monitoring",
        "Id": "7bilt3qa5ij5qqk25d2j47aza",
        ...
        "Containers": {
            "056bd02a2416c879680ab09fccb7f1727fdf2f8a97ee0cea57d5f4d21faf887a": {
                "Name": "monitoring_prometheus.1.oudo1n1qu5f8hqywvcfxoe4n9",
                "EndpointID": "92020da01862e40a0449c919228e354f564b6abeac6337f3a15fc143e5519da1",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c92b4883fa5c7390ab44442531b18365cd8a8ab0861c275e53c32874cf9c1b04": {
                "Name": "monitoring_exporter.173481td65qcdajte65b0jow0.ah2k9fl3sozmauxfge19o0ktc",
                "EndpointID": "00fb1100a1b28b6cc260a1a377ce593ce5d9ee803da191f6f2cb9097fae455fb",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

However, when I `docker exec` into the `prometheus` container, `nslookup exporter` I get the error message

```
/prometheus $ nslookup exporter
Server:     127.0.0.11
Address:    127.0.0.11:53

** server can't find exporter: NXDOMAIN

*** Can't find exporter: No answer
```

Same, when I try the same with the full qualified service name `monitoring_exporter`.

As expected, I also cannot `wget -O - http://monitoring_exporter:9100/metrics` - it returns an error message `wget: bad address 'monitoring_exporter:9100'`.

However, if I use the IP address of the exporter container, it works!
So, it seems to be no connectivity problem, but rather a name resolution problem.

Does anyone here has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through all the steps again, I finally found the problem myself!

If I create the network as `internal`, it works like expected:

```
docker network create --driver=overlay --scope=swarm --internal=true monitoring
```

The relevant part is **--internal=true**

Actually, I don't really understand why it needs to be internal, and why it wasn't and worked before, but at least now it works.